# Calculation of CRC-16(0xFFFF)

Tags: c#, crc16

I have data of 18005 hexadecimal frames, and I want to calculate `crc-16(0xffff)` of all frames simultaneously and then append.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking for completed code are not on-topic for StackOverflow. You haven't even specified the language that you wish to use, so there's no hope of anyone being able to answer this question usefully as it stands.

Comment: I use c# language

Answer (score 1):

Your CRC is not adequately specified. Are you trying to be compatible with some protocol that uses a 16-bit CRC? If so, you need to find out the parameters of that CRC. You can find [here a list of 28 different 16-bit CRC definitions](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm). The one you need might be one of those, or it might be yet another set of parameters.

It is not at all clear what the "(0xffff)" means in your name. The initial value? The final exclusive-or? The CRC of an empty string? Something else?

It is not clear what you mean by calculating the CRC of all frames "simultaneously". Why did you say simultaneously?

When appending the CRC, you will also need to know the bit or byte-order in which it should be appended. A two-byte CRC could be appended in little or big-endian order.

*Update:*

From the example CRCs in the comments, the desired CRC-16 is [CRC-16/CCITT-FALSE from the RevEng catalog](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat.crc-16-ccitt-false). You can use [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) to generate C code that computes this CRC. It will generate bit-wise, byte-wise, and word-wise code, at varying levels of speed and complexity. The bit-wise routine generated is:

```
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned crc16ccitt_false_bit(unsigned crc, void const *data, size_t len) {
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0xffff;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= (unsigned)(*(unsigned char const *)data++) << 8;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 0x8000 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x1021 : crc << 1;
    }
    crc &= 0xffff;
    return crc;
}
```

(When `buf` is `NULL`, the initial CRC value is returned.)

You can tell by inspection from your example streams if the CRC is appended in little or big-endian order.

Comment: Sir,I have data in which there are 18005 hexadecimal frames. One sample Frame is given as:

Comment: "AA01004AFF025773429200000000014048A76F64BE211C4648A76F64C0101C5648A76F64C08B137444154CBDBFA2073444154CBDC0570E2C44154CBDC0AE8C5F42700000B48B4296"

Comment: Above is my sample frame. I have 18004 more frames like this and i have to calculate and append crc-16 bit to all frames (at the end of frame) simultaneously. My each frame size is of 72 Bytes and i have to append two more bytes of crc which has initial value of 0xFFFF?

Comment: There are many possible CRC-16's. Which one? Do you have an example of a frame with a correct CRC?

Comment: This is my sample frame :  "AA01004AFF025773429200000000014048A76F64BE211C4648A76F64C0101C5648A76F64C08B137444154CBDBFA2073444154CBDC0570E2C44154CBDC0AE8C5F42700000B48B4296" .  Its correct crc ans is C2F0. This crc is referred by this website : ammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html

Comment: Another frame is : "AA01004AFF025773429200002710014048A76F65BE211C4448A76F65C0101C5648A76F65C08B137444154CBDBFA2073444154CBDC0570E2C44154CBDC0AE8C5F42700000349633DB" . Its crc answer is 9694. These crc ans are in hexadecimal mode.

Comment: website is lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html

Comment: Sir can you give an example how i insert *data in above function ?

Comment: I have to append crc in big endian order